Does Magento 2.4.6 requires MSI modules compulsory?
We have just updated a Magento core version from 2.4.5 to 2.4.6. Earlier we had disabled MSI modules on 2.4.5 version. However, after upgrading to 2.4.6, product pages showing error where some of the interfaces from Magento_Inventory*** (MSI modules) not found.

Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\GetProductSalableQtyInterface

We cross checked that no any third party or custom extension is accessing any class or interface from MSI modules. If we fix this error then it shows the next interface from other MSI modules and it goes on..
Please guide us through the solution.
Thanks in advance!

you need to look into the vendor folder too if you have installed some custom modules through composer
in my case i was getting same error as yours and get to know it was a custom module which was using Magento\InventorySalesApi in my case the module was Webkul_OutOfStockNotification
and the magento version was 2.4.7-p3
i believe you might get the issue earlier
but this could help others too

after upgrading to 2.4.6 please verify all below MSI module is disable if any one of them is enable then it will throw error.
Magento_Inventory
Magento_InventoryAdminUi
Magento_InventoryAdvancedCheckout
Magento_InventoryApi
Magento_InventoryBundleImportExport
Magento_InventoryBundleProduct
Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi
Magento_InventoryBundleProductIndexer
Magento_InventoryCatalog
Magento_InventorySales
Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi
Magento_InventoryCatalogApi
Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch
Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct
Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi
Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer
Magento_InventoryConfiguration
Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi
Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection
Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi
Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi
Magento_InventoryElasticsearch
Magento_InventoryExportStockApi
Magento_InventoryIndexer
Magento_InventorySalesApi
Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct
Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi
Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer
Magento_InventoryImportExport
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupApi
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupAdminUi
Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi
Magento_InventoryInStorePickup
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupGraphQl
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShippingApi
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupQuoteGraphQl
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSales
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSalesApi
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupQuote
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShipping
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShippingAdminUi
Magento_InventoryCache
Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification
Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi
Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi
Magento_InventoryProductAlert
Magento_InventoryRequisitionList
Magento_InventoryReservations
Magento_InventoryReservationCli
Magento_InventoryReservationsApi
Magento_InventoryExportStock
Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi
Magento_CatalogInventoryGraphQl
Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi
Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator
Magento_InventoryShipping
Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi
Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi
Magento_InventorySourceSelection
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupFrontend
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupMultishipping
Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSalesAdminUi
Magento_TwoFactorAuth
Magento_InventoryGraphQl
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupWebapiExtension


Yes, I confirm that all Magento_Inventory* modules (MSI modules) are disabled. Is the Magento_TwoFactorAuth MSI module?

No Magento_TwoFactorAuth is not MSI module
